# I am trying to install eas cli and am getting the error: zsh: command not found: eas

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo, eas

I am in the root folder and type:

```
yarn global add eas-cli
```

I then get:

```
yarn global v1.22.19
warning ../../package.json: No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Installed "eas-cli@0.54.1" with binaries:
```

Then I go to use eas by typing eas login and I get:

```
zsh: command not found: eas
```

Answer (score 21):

For some reason yarn does not add it to commands, might be a path issue, set-up issue with yarn.

using npm it worked fine

```
npm install -g eas-cli
```

Answer (score 4):

For mac and none of the above work. Check if your `.npmrc` has something like this

```
prefix=/Users/<username>/.npm-global
```

you can then add this line to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin
```

provided that you already installed eas or eas-cli

[.npm-global screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGhRE.png)

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me , when i added this to .zshrc file in Mac operating system with M1 chip

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(npm get prefix)/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a permission error, frequently happens on Yarn. Use:

```bash
$ sudo yarn global add eas-cli
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that it is installed globally with the -g flag. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used this command with "npx" like;

```
npx eas init --id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

then its ok now.

Answer (score 0):

check **expo-cli** package installed globally. and after install or check version **eas**

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I prefix it with `npx` and it worked fine

```
npx eas login
```

Answer (score -3):

it says

```
$ eas [COMMAND]
```

to use eas command.

Maybe you can type $ first before typing eas [command]
for example,

```
    $eas login
```

It worked to me.